# Graph of the function $y = 2 + (x + 1)^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I know that this function will have the behavior of $Y = X^3$ but as I will translate for this function $(Y = X^3)$?

I do this: 
$$(x + 1)^3 = x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 3 \quad y = x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 5$$
But don't know how to make the next step, for example I want to do the same with what I did with this function: 
$$y = x^4$$
$$y = (x^2)^2$$
$$Y = X^2 \quad Y = y^X = x^2 \rightarrow x = \sqrt X$$

It is possible?

****UPDATE**: The solution I wanted to find was:
Y = X³
y = 2 + (x + 1)³

y - 2 = (x + 1)³
Y = y - 2
X = x + 1

So the origin (0,0) of my graph is: 
y = 2
x = -1

This is pre-calculus and is only required to have an intuitive notion. I find it much more practical to think in the graph itself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** take the graph of $x^3$, shift it one unit to the left, and then two units upwards.

Comment: This is the only solution?

Comment: It is probably the most efficient one. Sure, you can start computing derivatives and second derivatives, limits at infinity, etc, to see the shape of the graph, but I mean.. you even noticed yourself that it should be similar to $x^3$! In general, if you define $g(x) = f(x-a)$, the graph of $g$ is the graph of $f$ shifted $a$ units to the right. And the graph of $h(x) = f(x)+b$ is the graph of $f$ shifted $b$ units upwards.

Answer (score 1):

for $y = \alpha + (x + \beta)^3$

take the graph of $x^3$, shift it $\beta$ unit to the left\right, and then $\alpha$ units upwards\downward it depends on the sign of $\alpha,\beta$.

Comment: If β it's positive then to the left or right? And α upwards or downward? This is true for all kinds of graph? (Obviously with different equation)

Comment: If sign of $\beta$ is not positive $\rightarrow$ shift $\beta$ units to the right

Comment: If the sign of $\alpha$ is not positive $\rightarrow$ shift $\alpha$ units downward